# Gravity Forms. View, Approvals plugin

Tags: php, gravity, gravity-forms-plugin

I have code like this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_entries_field_value', 'sh_filter_gform_entries_field_value', 9, 4 );
function sh_filter_gform_entries_field_value( $value, $form_id, $field_id, $entry ) {
   $translated_value = $value;
   if ( $field_id == 'approval_status' ) {
      switch ( $value ) {
         case 'pending' :
            $translated_value = esc_html__( 'Oczekująca', 'gravityformsapprovals' );
            break;
         case 'approved' :
            $translated_value = esc_html__( 'Zatwierdzona', 'gravityformsapprovals' );
            break;
         case 'rejected' :
            $translated_value = esc_html__( 'Odrzucona', 'gravityformsapprovals' );
            break;
      }
   }
   return $translated_value;
}
```

It's showing translated values of fields: pending, approved, rejected.
What i want is to make it also work in Gravity View, actualy it's not showing those values.

Comment: You can try same things, but in the view. Or pass an array to your controller

Comment: Can you help me do that?